# Periodically refresh/reload activity

Tags: android

I have one activity. OnCreate the activity gets the source (html) of a web page to a string and presents the result (after parsing it a bit) in a textview.

I would like the activity to reload/refresh periodically to always present the latest information.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I changed my app to have 2 tabs. Each tab starts its own activity. The first tab uses the activity described above. After i added the periodic update to that tab/activity there is a quite large delay when i try to switch to the other tab. Would it be better to solve this by using views in each tab? In that case how do i make so that only one of the tabs/views are updated periodically?

Comment: hi i got stuck with same problem if the below answer is solve u r problem then can u provide the code.I gone through the code but seems something going wrong.. it's too urgent thnx for any help ..:):) u can mail me on sumant4943@gmail.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all... separate the updating logic from your `onCreate` method. So, for instance, you can create an `updateHTML()`.

Then, you can use a `Timer` in order to update the page periodically:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

 private Timer autoUpdate;

 public void onCreate(Bundle b){
  super.onCreate(b);
  // whatever you have here
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  autoUpdate = new Timer();
  autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      updateHTML();
     }
    });
   }
  }, 0, 40000); // updates each 40 secs
 }

 private void updateHTML(){
  // your logic here
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  autoUpdate.cancel();
  super.onPause();
 }
}
```

Notice that I'm canceling the updating task on `onPause`, and that in this case the `updateHTML` method is executed each 40 secs (40000 milliseconds). Also, make sure you import these two classes: `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I changed my app to have 2 tabs. Each tab starts its own activity. The first tab uses the activity described above. After i added the periodic update to that tab/activity there is a quite large delay when i try to switch to the other tab. Would it be better to solve this by using views in each tab? In that case how do i make so that only one of the tabs/views are updated periodically?