# How to design a service to do a job for a few seconds, destroy itself and re-spawn periodically?

Tags: android, android-service

In regards to this SO Q.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177404/progressbuilder-long-operation-leads-lauching-activity-service-to-crash-while-co :

What could be a good way for a service to poll an OS process running, catch some progress for a seconds or two and then shutdown itself?

Is the `TimerTask()` an option? (as described here: [Periodically refresh/reload activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701106/periodically-refresh-reload-activity), but with the code to launch and then close the service).

Or maybe the `AlarmManager` is a better alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to shut down a Service, it's not actually working.
If you want to do something once in a while consider using an AlarmManager as its the only way to wake up device when its sleeping, then call your service from alarm receiver.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: Thanks anyway, I resolved with a different approach.